# Get execution time and clock cycle in C

Tags: c, time, clock

I'm trying to get approximate execution time of a simple code using clock() function in C. I use a 16MHz pipeline chip so the throughput in ideal case is 1.

```
void main(){
  short i1, i2, sum = 0;
  clock_t start = clock();
  for(i1 = 0; i1 < 128; i1++)
  {
   for(i2 = 0; i2 < 128; i2++)
   {
      sum += (short)((i1+ i2) + 4);
   }
  }
  clock_t end = clock();
  double Num_Of_Clocks = end - start;
  double Execution_Time = (Num_Of_Clocks/CLOCK_PER_SECOND);
  printf("Exectuion Time is : %2.10f seconds and Number of Clocks: %2.3f", Execution_Time, Num_Of_Clocks);
}
```

the result is:

```
Execution Time is : 0.0000043125 and Number of Clocks: 69.000
```

Is it possible to do about 81000 (128*128 *5) operations just in 69 clock cycles? does the Clock() function work well?

The assembly output is:

```
_main:
    push    (r4,r5,lr)
    sub sp, #8
    jsr _clock
    mov r4, r0
    mov r5, r1
    mov r0, #0
    mov r1, #0
.Llabel.3.1:
    cmp ge, r1, #128
    jpt .Llabel.3.3
    mov r2, #0
.Llabel.3.4:
    cmp ge, r2, #128
    jpt .Llabel.3.6
    mov r3, r1
    add r3, r2
    add r3, #4
    add r0, r3
.Llabel.3.5:
    add r2, #1
    jmp .Llabel.3.4
.Llabel.3.6:
.Llabel.3.2:
    add r1, #1
    jmp .Llabel.3.1
.Llabel.3.3:
    jsr _clock
    sub r1, r5
    sbc r0, r4
    jsr $___floatsisf
    mov r4, r0
    mov r5, r1
    mov a13, #___stemp1
    ldw r2, @[a13 + 0]
    ldw r3, @[a13 + 2]
    mov r10, r2
    mov r11, r3
    mov r0, r4
    mov r1, r5
    jsr $___divsf3
    ldw @[sp + 2], r0
    ldw @[sp + 4], r1
    ldw @[sp + 6], r4
    ldw @[sp + 8], r5
    mov a10, #___str_0
    jsr _printf
    mov r0, #0
    jmp .Llabel.3.7
    jmp .Llabel.3.7
.Llabel.3.7:
    add sp, #8
    pop_ret (r4,r5,lr)
```

Comment: Don't use casts unless they are really necessary. `sum += (short)((i1+ i2) + 4)` has a useless cast. And provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Olaf removing the cast doesn't change anything. I think the code is simple enough and I just need to find out does clock() function work correctly or am I using the function Clock() wrong?

Comment: I did not say it changes something **here**. But it does no good either and _can_ cause harm. It is a general advice. Never ever add a cast to e.g. silence a warning unless you really know about its implications! (from your comment I understand you are not aware why you added it at all).

Comment: @Olaf I added the assembly output of the loop to make it more complete or verifiable

Comment: @Olaf yes you are right. I had to test the given code so I didn't change the code. Thanks for your suggestion you mentioned to a useful point.

Comment: I still don't see a [mcve]. You should read the comments and follow the links!

Comment: @Olaf Ok I will read and try to do that but do you mind to help me through the asked question?

Comment: I don't think that dividing clock by 16 MHz is correct, I've never seen an architecture where it actually returns the number of CPU cycles executed; by dividing your number of operations by 69 I'm more inclined to think that the clock counter ticks every 1024 CPU cycles. Is that CLOCK_PER_SECOND provided by your toolchain or you made that up? You should really look up how clock is implemented in your toolchain to understand exactly what that number means.

Comment: @MatteoItalia thanks, the CLOCK_PER_SECOND constant is defined 60 in my tool but it mentioned that it must be set based on timer frequency. 60 is not a sensible value in comparison with chip frequency. It confuses me :?

Comment: There is no reason for the compiler to include your loop at all, since the result is a constant value.  Furthermore, you never use `sum` anyway.  A proper optimization would completely remove these.

Comment: @MatteoItalia how can I get an approximate execution time in such cases? I'm in trouble with this things.

Comment: @paddy but the assembly result of compiler shows that the loop is not optimized and is included in calculation. I added the assembly output.

Comment: Really, I'd try to look up the clock implementation and see what kind of hardware timer it is using.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Thanks a lot :)